# Where should I ask WordPress questions?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, wordpress-se

I'm trying to be a "good boy" and ask questions on the site where they belong. However lately I encountered several cases where I wasn't sure which site to choose: StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser or Doctype.

Specifically, these are questions about WordPress hosted blogs. The reason it's tricky is because the choice of site **depends on the answer**, but I don't know the answer until I ask my question... To clarify, the answer to my question may be:

1. A tweak in the PHP source code (StackOverflow)
2. A request to my hosting provider (ServerFault, or maybe SuperUser)
3. A configuration tweak (SuperUser)
4. A CSS fix (Doctype)

I am using my best judgement, and have asked questions on most of the sites. Here [are](https://serverfault.com/questions/56351/wordpress-how-to-use-non-ugly-permalinks-without-access-to-htaccess) [several](http://doctype.com/wordpress-subscribe2-plugin-escapes-characters-blog-name-when-sending-email) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329205/wordpress-subscribe2-plugin-escapes-characters-in-blog-name-when-sending-email).

However, now I have a question and I really don't know where to ask it: the question is how I can download a complete theme after I made code changes to it on the server, so that I can deploy that exact theme on another blog, without downloading file-by-file. I really don't know where the solution will come from...

What do you think? What is the best practice for asking WordPress related questions?

Comment: What about now that we have Web Apps and Web Masters? Can we change now?

Comment: exactly i want to know the same answer for this question. where can i ask wordpress related questions???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does depend on the type of question, as some might be more programming specific than others.  However, if you are in doubt, I would suggest that you start with SuperUser, as you are asking for answers to questions you have using a third party software/service, from others that use that same software/service.

**Update:**

*There is a specific Stack Exchange site dedicated to WordPress related* questions: 
[wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Am I the only one who thinks wordpress.org?  They have [forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) for the base install and some plugins have forums and mailing lists.  If that fails, there's the [wordpress plugin forum](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/10) and e-mailing the author; besides all the usual googling you do about your problem before asking.

There are a ton of open source apps - phpBB, wordpress, and so on, and they all have evolved their **own** support channels.  These types of questions: "I can't get plugin X of Semi-Obscure App Y working" tend to interest a very few people, and grow the size of the active and new pages to the point where for 95% of the people the signal to noise ratio is way low.  (Or at least lower than it used to be 4-5 months ago)

I'm not picking on you, and I *do think* there are *some* wordpress or phpBB related questions that are worth putting on Stackoverflow, but not the majority of them.  **Your two questions are worthwhile**, because you abstract them very far away from wordpress.  I think that's the key.  When you abstract the problem far enough away where it's a question you don't need any specialized knowledge about, it becomes obvious which site to post it on.

Comment: @Tom: the WordPress forums are not very helpful, I tried them all for each of my questions. Usually you see a question, maybe one non-helpful answer, and the topic is closed. I believe the StackOverflow family of sites to be better suited for these questions. I always try to abstract the most while writing questions, but WordPress is WordPress... +1 because it's a valid option, but IMHO (and very sadly so) - not a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a solid theory about where to ask which questions. If it's theme-modification (coding), then go to SO. As for downloading a theme, this sounds more like a superuser question. It's frustrating though, because for some reason it seems as though there's another option missing, but since I can't place my finger on it, superuser because the default.

Comment: Superuser "becomes" the default? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Superuser is viewed (not by me, but apparently by the majority) as the trashbin for all questions that don't fit on SF/SO/MSO.

Comment: @Jonathan: I was referring to what I think is a typo in your answer's last words ("superuser because the default") - just to make sure I'm getting you correctly...