# Where should CMS questions go to?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am sure a lot of developers/ system admins/ power users have question about a CMS such as Drupal or Joomla, but it seems that there is no proper place for those questions. CMS questions can be about programming (developers), configuration (that's a system admin's job) and web design.

What do you think?

Comment: Same places WordPress questions go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/where-should-i-ask-wordpress-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since this question has been asked, but a couple of CMSes and related platforms meanwhile have their own Stack Exchange sites, and many welcome non-programming questions which would be off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please check their Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic) because the exact scope differs from site to site.

- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
- [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)
- [Expression Engine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/)
- [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/)
- [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/)
- [Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/)
- [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

You might find more in the [Technology section](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-answers) of the list of sites in the network.

Answer (score 2):

I think that they should go where they belong:

- Programming a CMS plugin: [Stack Overflow](https://StackOverflow.com)
- Setting up Apache to use Drupal: [Server Fault](https://ServerFault.com)
- How to write a template for a CMS: [Stack Overflow](https://StackOverflow.com) (or, gasp, doctype)
- How to use certain CMS to write content: [Super User](https://superuser.com)

I'm sure you can generalize from here :-)

If you don't know where to ask because you don't know what it'll require, I think Super User is the place to start. It'll soon enough get moved where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

**Dedicated CMS sites** on Stack Exchange:

- Craft CMS: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com
- Drupal: https://drupal.stackexchange.com
- Expression Engine: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com
- Joomla: https://joomla.stackexchange.com
- Magento: https://magento.stackexchange.com
- Salesforce: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com
- SharePoint: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com
- Tridion: https://tridion.stackexchange.com

**Questions about other CMSs** may be asked here on webmasters.stackexchange.com.

To discover projects of **new communities** or create one, visit the Area 51 section: https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. Answer was edited, taking into account the rules in the link you provided.